# Flow control - long text area input remove validation when clicking previous button on the flow screen

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a flow where I put in a long text area control with the **require** option checked. I am not sure why the validation message '**Complete this field**' pops up when the user clicks on the previous button. I thought the validations apply only when moving forward.
[image]

Comment: Hi Sumesh, I hope that will not stop you to navigate previous screen . This is getting triggered even not on click on previous as well if you click some where in that screen as well you will face this error message and which will not stop the process. This will only stop from moving to the next screen

Comment: Thanks @SaiPraveenKakkirala thats what I am seeing. its weird.